# Prolog With Lists

Tags: list, prolog

I received this problem and I can't get it done, I don't know what I've done wrong, can someone help me ?

> Write a predicate to add a value v after 1-st, 2-nd, 4-th, 8-th, … element in a list.

```
% add(L:list, E:Number, P:Number, C:number, H:List)
% add(i,i,i,i,o)

add([],_,_,_,[]).
add([_|T],E,P,C,[HR|TR]) :-
   P =:= C,
   HR is E,
   C is C+1,
   P is P*2,
   add(T,E,P,C,TR).
add([H|T],E,P,C,[H|TR]) :-
   P =\= C,
   C is C+1,
   add(T,E,P,C,TR).
```

Comment: What are E,P,C  and how do you use them??

Comment: They are variablem, so E stands for the number that needs to be added, P the position where it needs to be added (1,2,4,8 ...) and C the current position. P I increases it to know at everytime at what position I am, and P I multiply it by 2 when i find a possition and insert the value

Comment: So you need to add P after every even position? Does `add` have to take 5 arguments ?

Comment: I tougt that i need 5 for solving the problem, and i need to insert E at every C possition so i count the possitions with P

Comment: You mean at every P position from what I see you tried (and you count using C)??

Comment: Yes, sorry I misteken p for c

Comment: take a look at my answer, hope it helps...

Comment: Yes it works, thank you very much :D

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The main problem is that when a variable in Prolog gets instantiated you can't change the value e.g increase the value so you need to use a new variable:

```
add([],_,_,_,[]).
add([H|T],E,P,C,[H,E|TR]) :-
   P =:= C, 
   C1 is C+1,
   P1 is P*2,
   add(T,E,P1,C1,TR).
add([H|T],E,P,C,[H|TR]) :-
   P =\= C,
   C1 is C+1,
   add(T,E,P,C1,TR).
```

Example:

```
?- add([1,2,3,4],10,1,1,L).
L = [1, 10, 2, 10, 3, 4, 10] ;
false.
```

Answer (score 6):

Here's another possibility to define such a predicate. Whenever you are describing lists it is worthwhile to consider using DCGs since they yield easily readable code. First let's observe that there's only need for three arguments, namely the list, the element to be inserted and the list with the element already inserted at the desired positions. The arguments `P` and `C` are only needed for bookkeeping purposes so it's opportune to hide them inside the predicate. And since we're already about to redesign the predicates interface let's also give it a more descriptive name that reflects its relational nature, say list_e_inserted/3:

```
list_e_inserted(L,E,I) :-
   phrase(inserted(L,E,1,1),I).  % the DCG inserted//4 describes the list I

inserted([],_E,_P,_C) -->        % if the list L is empty  
   [].                           % the list I is empty as well
inserted([H|T],E,P,P) -->        % if P and C are equal
   {P1 is P*2, C1 is P+1},       % P is doubled and C is increased
   [H,E],                        % H is in the list I, followed by E
   inserted(T,E,P1,C1).          % the same holds for T,E,P1,C1
inserted([H|T],E,P,C) -->        % if P and C are
   {dif(P,C), C1 is C+1},        % different C is increased
   [H],                          % H is in the list I
   inserted(T,E,P,C1).           % the same holds for T,E,P,C1
```

Now let's see the predicate at work:

```
?- list_e_inserted([],10,I).
I = [].

?- list_e_inserted([1],10,I).
I = [1, 10] ;
false.

?- list_e_inserted([1,2],10,I).
I = [1, 10, 2, 10] ;
false.

?- list_e_inserted([1,2,3],10,I).
I = [1, 10, 2, 10, 3] ;
false.

?- list_e_inserted([1,2,3,4],10,I).
I = [1, 10, 2, 10, 3, 4, 10] ;
false.
```

The predicate also works in the other direction:

```
?- list_e_inserted(L,E,[1,10,2,10,3,4,10,5]).
L = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
E = 10 ;
false.
```

And the most general query also yields the desired solutions:

```
?- list_e_inserted(L,E,I).
L = I, I = [] ;
L = [_G23],
I = [_G23, E] ;
L = [_G23, _G35],
I = [_G23, E, _G35, E] ;
L = [_G23, _G35, _G47],
I = [_G23, E, _G35, E, _G47] ;
L = [_G23, _G35, _G47, _G53],
I = [_G23, E, _G35, E, _G47, _G53, E] ;
.
.
.
```